# How to join two v-html in one

Tags: vue.js

I wonder if it's possible to join 2 `v-html` in one line together or not? if not any alternative solution will be appreciated.

## code

I have something like this:

```
<p v-html="item.number">
  <div v-html="item.body"></div>
</p>
```

Which results like this:

[image: one]

What I'm looking for is go have something like:

> 3 At the designated....

so the item number is left side of the item body instead of above it (*because of paragraph tags*)

any idea?

## Update

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "books",
        data() {
            return {
                book_slug: '',
                slug: '',
                verses: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getBooks: function(){
                this.book_slug = this.$route.params.book_slug
                this.slug = this.$route.params.slug
                axios.get('/api/'+this.$route.params.book_slug+'/'+this.$route.params.slug+'/'+this.$route.params.slug).then((res) => {
                    this.verses = res.data.verses
                    console.log(res.data)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                });
            },
            myHTML: function(item) {
                return item.number+" "+item.body+" ";
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getBooks();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A) Are you really sure you need v-html? B) Are you familiar with slots?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty A) for body part at least i need because it has html tags B) not 100%

Comment: You can use <template> as that gets removed on render as long as it isn't the child of another <template>.

Comment: @Arc would you care share a sample please?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a method to return your HTML with both your item values

```
methods: {
  myHTML: function(item) {
    return item.number+"<div>"+item.body+"</div>";
  }
}
```

And then use your method property myHTML within v-html in your template tag, pass in the item

```
v-html="myHTML(item)"
```

Comment: it says: `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined"`

Comment: How is item set?  Is it part of your local data object?

Comment: items are from verses array `data() {
            return {
                book_slug: '',
                slug: '',
                verses: []
            }
        },`   it's a loop

Comment: now it return this `Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.getBooks is not a function"`

Comment: Okay, updated my answer to a method that will work for your use case

Comment: it says `Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.getBooks is not a function"` wait i update my code for you

Comment: I think you added a second methods function, where you should add myHTML as a second function within your "methods" section?

Comment: Yes, you have two methods sections, just put them into one

Comment: yet i have issue of those <p> tags

Comment: should just be <p v-html="myHTML(item)"></p>, which given the above logic will inject a div with the item body into your p tag with a number. What is your desired format?

Comment: this is the html i receive in view now https://ibb.co/yFSyj4y

Comment: PS: i removed `div` from `myHTML` in order to clean up the final html code

Comment: Yes, just return a complete block of HTML code from your method, and you'll be able to include tags and formatting as desired. You can also variables stored in your local data object in addition to the item passed in, using this.localParamName

Comment: i think i need to edit all my rows in table :/ as results are like: `3 <p>text here</p>` basically with this method or my default set result is the same. apparently there is no way to get rid of `<p>` tag in my texts.